# How can I get Visual C 6 help (MSDN) to work under Windows 10?

Tags: mfc, windows-10, msdn, visual-c++-6

I'm using Visual Studio 6 for updating an old MFC4.2 project and I'd like to get the MSDN SDK/MFC help to work again under windows 10. Right now when I press F1 it reports "Unable to display Help: a required component is missing. Please reinstall".

Seeing as this is a fresh install I suspect the required component that is missing is part of the OS. My first guess was it was Winhlp32 which was removed in the Vista era.  I followed the excellent instructions on https://github.com/knuth-konrad/winhlp32-on-windows10 to reinstall winhlp32.exe and that loads just fine now. If I navigate manually to where the help files are stored I can double click and read them fine, but it turns out that's not the missing dependency that allows VC6 to load the function reference when you press F1 in the editor.

Also, Visual C++ 6 worked fine under Windows 7, so I think something more subtle must have changed.

There are obvious workarounds and I've even used them in different contexts - a virtual machine running XP, or using online access to MSDN, but in my particular case neither of those are a good solution.

Comment: I have successfully installed the old WinHlp32 (replacing the new "stub" version) on Win10, because we wanted to run an old version of Borland Delphi. The installation was far far less complicated that the procedure described at github, just two or three steps. It opened help files as before. Before researching it further, I would say first check if your installation is OK, just double-click on a .hlp file, and see if it actually works. WinHlp32 is a viewer associated to .hlp files, so they should be opened even outside of Visual Studio. Your question is not MFC-related btw.

Comment: the files open fine outside visual studio. Question edited to reflect this.